# Plot subsets of one variable on x-y axis (avoid spreading/reshaping data frame)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I wonder whether it's possible to plot row subsets of one variable in 
a x-y axis without having to spread/reshape the data frame?

## Fake data

```
library(tidyverse)
id <- 1:6
size <- c(5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8)
colour <- rep(c("red", "blue", "green"), 2)
df <- data.frame(id, size, colour)
```

## Attempt

```
x11()
ggplot(data = filter(df, colour %in% c("blue", "red")),
       aes(x = size[colour == "blue"],
           y = size[colour == "red"])) +
  geom_point()
```

## Desired result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. One solution is to submit vector to `aes` directly (IMO this is abuse of `ggplot2`, but right now I can't think of any other solution).

```
# Subset data once so we wouldn't need to subset twice for nrow 
id <- 1:6
size <- c(5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8)
colour <- rep(c("red", "blue", "green"), 2)
df <- data.frame(id, size, colour)
pd <- subset(df, colour %in% c("blue", "red"))

# Use dummy empty data.frame
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(), 
       # Submit x,y values as vectors that go every second entry
       aes(pd$size[seq(2, nrow(pd), 2)], pd$size[seq(1, nrow(pd), 2)])) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a lot! Apologies for late reply.